# Jordan form from the minimal polynomial $m_A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, jordan-algebras

Let the matrix

\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
4 & 3 & 2 \\\
2 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

So far I found the characteristic polynomial $C_A(x)=(x-3)(x-1)^2$ and the minimal polynomial $m_A(x)=(x-3)(x-1)^2$. The solution sheet explains that the Jordan matrix has the form

\begin{equation}
J_1=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & * & *\\
* & 1 & * \\\
* & * & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation} or

\begin{equation}
J_2=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & * & *\\
* & 1 & 1 \\\
* & * & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

I know that since $m_a$ has a double root, we know that $A$ is not diagonalizable, so the Jordan form is the matrix $J_2$.

Does someone could explain where come from the matrix $J_1$ and $J_2$? What outcome can allow us to conclude the $J_1$ and $J_2$ form?

Comment: @Peter Which blocks are you talking about?

Comment: I have three different blocks in head actually : \begin{equation}
J_2=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & * & *\\
* & 1 & * \\\
* & * & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}, \begin{equation}
J_2=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & * & *\\
* & 1 & 1 \\\
* & * & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} and \begin{equation}
J_2=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & *\\
* & 1 & 1 \\\
* & * & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}... Why two?

Comment: @Dr.Dray Your last matrix is not in Jordan normal form.

Comment: $\pmatrix {1&1\\0&1}$ is a Jordan-block of size $2$.

Comment: So, in the given case, we have the block containing only one element (the $3$) and the block corresponding to $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution sheet is wrong.

The characterstic equation and minimal polynomial are enough to tell us what the Jordan normal form of a $2 \times 2$ or a $3 \times 3$ matrix is.

Here $C_A(x)=(x-3)(x-1)^2$, so we know that the Jordan normal form will have exactly one $3$ and two $1$s on the diagonal.

Since the minimal polynomial is $m_A(x)=(x-3)(x-1)^2$, we know that the longest Jordan chain of $\lambda = 3$ is of length $1$, and the longest Jordan chain of $\lambda = 1$ is of length $2$, so the Jordan normal form is your $J_2$.

If on the other hand we had $m_A(x)=(x-3)(x-1)$, then we would have $J_1$.

Comment: I think, that the exercise was to rule out the first case. The minimal polynomial probably was not given in advance.

Comment: @Peter That would make more sense. Though, in this case, given the characteristic equation, it is easy enough to test that $(A - 3)(A-1) \neq 0_3$, so we must have $C_A(x) = m_A(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

It easy to see that for 
$J=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&3\end{array}\right)$ we have $(J-3E)(J-E)^2=0$ where $E$ is the identity matrix, but $(J-3E)(J-E)\neq0$. Then the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial are equal.

Comment: so, $A$ and $J_2$ are in the same conjugacy class of $3\times 3$ matrices

Comment: $J_2$ comes from the process of pseudo-diagonalization for square matrices

Comment: use as in this example: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordanform+%7B%7B4%2C67%7D%2C%7B65%2C8%7D%7D&x=9&y=6 to robotize some part of the calculations